# 'docker-compose up' stops during the process

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using Docker for Mac on my Mac OS 10.12.6.
I'm trying to run `docker-compose up` but it stops at the line where it says `db_1 | Version: '5.7.23'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)`. ([screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHfeU.jpg)) There are no error messages shown, it just stops processing there (I've waited for over 15 mins and nothing seems to happen) so I have to force-quit by pressing Ctrl + C and give up.
The thing is that there is no such path as '/var/run/mysqld' so I `mkdir /var/run/mysqld` and `touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`, however, it doesn't change the situation. I've also tried `docker-compose build` & `docker-compose up`, but it doesn't help either.

My docker-compose.yml is:

[screenshot of my docker-compose.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btH9R.jpg)

My directory structure is as follows:

my_app
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── containers
│ ├── mysql
│ │ ├── Dockerfile
│ │ ├── my.cnf
│ │ └── password.yml
│ ├── nginx
│ │ ├── Dockerfile
│ │ ├── default.conf
│ │ └── nginx.conf
│ ├── ruby
│ │ ├── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml

What can I possibly do to fix this problem? I'm really stuck and any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What output did you expect? Did you mean to `docker-compose up -d`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
To get the message of success or something similar on my terminal and I want to see the 'Yay! You are on Rails!' page when I access to localhost:3000.

Comment: Have you tried navigating to localhost:3000 when the terminal output stops?

Comment: OMG it's up... I am so silly that I never even thought of trying that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was already working fine, I just had to navigate to localhost:3000. Silly me.